# Помогите разобраться с заданием по спискам

Tags: javascript

Функция #3 "recursion"
Реализовать функцию recursion, которая получает на вход дерево представленное объектом следующей структуры:

```js
let tree = {
  "value": 100,
  "left": {
    "value": 90,
    "left": {
      "value": 70
    },
    "right": {
      "value": 99
    }
  },
  "right": {
    "value": 120,
    "left": {
      "value": 110
    },
    "right": {
      "value": 130
    }
  }
};

function recursion(tree) {
}

let array = recursion(tree);
console.log(array); // [[100], [90, 120], [70,99,110,130]]
```

и преобразует его в массив вида [[100], [90, 120], [70,99,110,130]].

Для решения должна использоваться рекурсия

Как я понял, это список, но идей как решить подобное нет вообще. Есть идеи?

Comment: объявляете массив результата и запускаете рекурсию.  При каждом вызове считаете глубину. При каждом посещении узла на глубине `z` в масив  результата `result[z]` добавляете посещенный элемент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная задача предполагает обход дерева в ширину.

На каждом шаге нужно брать значения доступных узлов, например с помощью метода [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Далее, получить список узлов следующего уровня - это все узлы `left` и `right` у доступных узлов, и применить к ним рекурсивно уже имеющуюся функцию.

Останавливать рекурсию можно когда в полученном списке не останется доступных узлов.

Пример реализации:

```js
let tree = {
  "value": 100,
  "left": {
    "value": 90,
    "left": {
      "value": 70
    },
    "right": {
      "value": 99
    }
  },
  "right": {
    "value": 120,
    "left": {
      "value": 110
    },
    "right": {
      "value": 130
    }
  }
};

function recursion(...tree) {
  if (tree.length == 0) return [];
  var v = tree.map(n => n.value);

  return [v, ...recursion(...tree.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur.left, cur.right), []).filter(n => n))];
}

let array = recursion(tree);
console.log(array); // [[100], [90, 120], [70,99,110,130]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tree = {
  "value": 100,
  "left": {
    "value": 90,
    "left": { "value": 70 },
    "right": { "value": 99 }
  },
  "right": {
    "value": 120,
    "left": { "value": 110 },
    "right": { "value": 130 }
  }
};

function recursion(tree) {
  var res = []
  
  ~function go(tree, i) {
    if (!tree) return
  
    (res[i] = res[i] || []).push(tree.value)
    go(tree.left, i+1)
    go(tree.right, i+1)
  }(tree, 0)
  
  return res
}

let array = recursion(tree);
console.log(array); // [[100], [90, 120], [70,99,110,130]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tree = {
  "value": 100,
  "left": {
    "value": 90,
    "left": { "value": 70 },
    "right": { "value": 99 }
  },
  "right": {
    "value": 120,
    "left": { "value": 110 },
    "right": { "value": 130 }
  }
};

function recursion(tree, level, result) {
  if (!tree)
    return;
    
  level = level || 0;
  result = result || [];

  (result[level] = result[level] || []).push(tree.value);
  
  recursion(tree.left, level + 1, result);
  recursion(tree.right, level + 1, result);

  return result;
}

let array = recursion(tree);
console.log(array); // [[100], [90, 120], [70,99,110,130]]
```

Comment: Почти как моё...

Comment: @Qwertiy Пока писал - не подглядывал ).

Comment: Вообще, в условии говорится, что "должна использоваться рекурсия", но не говорится, что именно функция `recursion` должна быть рекурсивной)